# Problems with the output of the integral function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I write here because I've some problems when I want to integrate this quantity with respect to z:

[image]

rH, a and z are real values, being TT4 a real value too and I especify that in the assumptions of the integral, but the result is the next:

[image]

As you can see there are a lot of roots like:

[image]

being the result completely imaginary. I can't understand why if I put the assumptions and my integrating is real. I substituted a and rH for real values, plotting in z values and I obtained a real function... I dont know why Mathematica is not able to do the integral. Maybe, do you know where is the problem?

Thank you everyone for the attention!

PS1: Sorry for repost the question but my last question was closed for not adding aditional information. Now I added the information they asked me so I expect that mods don't close it :S

PS2: I'm sorry, I put here the code. I solve the mistake that said bbgodfrey but the result is the same:

```
TT4 = ((rH (a^2 + rH^2) z Sqrt[3] 4 \[Pi]^2 (54 rH^12 + 2 a^12 z^12 +18 a^2 rH^10 (2 + 11 z^2) + 3 a^4 rH^8 z^2 (41 + 93 z^2) + 2 a^10 rH^2 z^6 (4 + 2 z^2 + 9 z^4) + a^8 rH^4 z^2 (-4 + 24 z^2 + 55 z^4 + 75 z^6) +2 a^6 rH^6 (-1 + 5 z^2 + 72 z^4 + 96 z^6)))/(16 G \[Pi] (rH^2 + a^2 z^2)^(3/2) (3 rH^4 + a^4 z^4 + a^2 rH^2 (1 + 3 z^2))^(5/2))) 
Int1 = Integrate[TT4, z, Assumptions -> {TT4 \[Element] Reals, a \[Element] Reals,rH \[Element] Reals, z \[Element] Reals, 0 <= z <= 1, rH > a >= 0}]
```

Tell me if I need to put any additional information.

Comment: With v12.2, your code successfully evaluates. The result is very complicated and involves complicated arguments to `EllipticE` and `EllipticF`. Did you `Clear` your old definitions?

Comment: I expect that the result involves EllipticE and EllipticF functions but the problem is the imaginary roots inside them. I've tried it but it seems is not the problem.

Comment: You are evaluating an indefinite integral (antiderivative) which has an implied arbitrary constant. In general, the arbitrary constant can be **complex**. Further, real expressions can contain imaginary or complex components as long as the imaginary elements all cancel out. For example, `3/2 - (1/4)*(39 + 26*I)^(1/3)*(1 - I*Sqrt[3]) 
 - (13^(2/3)*(1 + I*Sqrt[3]))/(4*(3 + 2*I)^(1/3))` is real

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bob Hanlon. The problem is that I'm computing a physic real quantity and that can't be possible. Are you saying that maybe the whole quantity simplified is maybe real? I've tried to simplify it but I didnt get it.

Comment: When calculating an indefinite integral (antiderivative) there is no guarantee that the resulting expression is real. If you are expecting a real result, the imaginary component of the result should be constant, i.e., the derivative of that imaginary component is zero. The only guarantee is that the derivative of the antiderivative should be the original integrand. The algorithm used to calculate the integral operates in the complex domain and it will in general produce complex results. The complex result should reduce to a real result when your limits of integration are specified.

Comment: But I don't understand why if we can consider the integral of a function like the area under the function... how is it possible that a real function has a imaginary area?...

Comment: To consider the integral as the area under the function you need to specify the limits of integration, i.e., a definite integral rather than an indefinite integral. For the definite integral, the arbitrary constant of integration of the indefinite integral is determined and canceled out. If the arbitrary constant is imaginary or complex, its cancellation removes the imaginary component.

Comment: Okay, I get what are you saying.. If I do Int[1]- Int[0] the integration constant is deleted but in this case my mathematica collapse when I put the integration limit.  z is equal to Cos[theta] and theta goes from 0 to pi/2. Then z goes from 1 to 0... If I try to solve the integration just like a definite integral, my mathematica stop work but If I solve it like a indefinite integral and after that I substitute the values of z, the imaginary part stay in the solution and doesnt disappear.